# How do I get information about whether any sound is playing via Web Audio?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have a use case where I need information about whether any audio is playing (as in, is sound coming out of the speakers or is it not) through the Web Audio API, from a `MediaElementSource`.

I've tried to add an `AnalyserNode` and figure out the RMS with this code:

```
getVolume () {
  let buffer = new Uint8Array(this.$data.audio.analyzer.fftSize)
  this.$data.audio.analyzer.getByteTimeDomainData(buffer)
  let rms = 0
  buffer.forEach(i => {
    rms += i * i
  })
  rms /= buffer.length
  rms = Math.sqrt(rms)
  return rms
}
```

But this just returns `128` during the entire runtime of my audio. Am I doing something wrong? This is the graph for my audio:

```
MediaElementAudioSource -> Analyser -> AudioDestination
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at what [getByteTimeDomainData](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-analysernode-getbytetimedomaindata) actually returns. 128 represents zero.  I think this method is really meant for visualization.  If you want to do analysis of some sort, use [getFloatTimeDomainData](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-analysernode-getfloattimedomaindata).  Then you'll see 0 values when things are silent.